# Python Django UpdateView: 404 not found

Tags: django, updateview

I'm using the built in class based views, in this case the UpdateView. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) doesn't give any hints towards how the `urls.py` must look like. Which url pattern is matched by that generic view, so that I can update a particular object (e.g. with id 1 in the database)? I tried:

```
path("myroute/<int:pk>/", views.myUpdateView.as_view(), name="myname")
```

The view behind `views.myUpdateView` is a `django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView` and when I navigate to let's say `myroute/1/` I get a 404 error. How am I supposed to use that generic view? I was just guessing that it must somehow fetch the pk parameter from my URL, but I see no documentation for that part? Sorry for not including the template ecetera, but it's not really needed here because my question is so simple: which url pattern(s) is (are) processed by the UpdateView? Did I overlook something in the documentation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a record in your DB with a primary key (PK) of 1? If there isn't then one would expect the 404 not found error.

Comment: ... sorry. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I was testing with hardcoded pks and had 2 objects in the database all the time. I had forgotten that I had tried a few things (delete, re-create etc) and therefore their ids are not 1 and 2 anymore but instead of course got incremented ... thank you for your very logical comment :)

Comment: Maybe one more follow up, because I was wondering this too: how is it obvious, that the parameter name must be "pk"? I didn't see that in the documentation, I think I saw it in some example. How did people find out if it's not documented?

Comment: It is in the docs somewhere.  It is hard to find because there is so much documentation :)

Comment: You can also override object getter in `UpdateView` and create new instance if it does not exists and redirect to it (but it's probably not desired solution for you).